# Upgrade MySql from 5.6.25 to 5.7 MAMP

Tags: mysql, mamp

I am trying to upgrade my MAMP sql from 5.6 to 5.7 but am running into problems. Here is the script i'm following:

```
#!/bin/sh

wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.7/mysql-5.7.9- osx10.10-x86_64.tar.gz
tar xfvz mysql-5.7*

echo "stopping mamp"
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/stop.sh
sudo killall httpd mysqld

echo "creating backup"
sudo rsync -a /Applications/MAMP ~/Desktop/MAMP-Backup

echo "copy bin"
sudo rsync -av mysql-5.7.*/bin/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ --exclude=mysqld_multi --exclude=mysqld_safe

echo "copy share"
sudo rsync -av mysql-5.7.*/share/* /Applications/MAMP/Library/share/

echo "fixing access (workaround)"
sudo chmod -R o+rw  /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
sudo chmod -R o+rw  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/

echo "starting mamp"
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
sudo /Applications/MAMP/bin/start.sh

echo "migrate to new version"
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_upgrade --user=root --password=root --host=localhost --port=3306
```

And here is my error on the last migration part:

```
mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql
mysql_upgrade: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql_upgrade: Got error: 2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) while connecting to the MySQL server
```

Upgrade process encountered error and will not continue.

I look for `/tmp/mysql.sock` but I can only find this `/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.lock`

Any reason this is happening?

Comment: `service mysql start`?

Comment: Questions on professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](//http://serverfault.com/).

Comment: The Server will not start and Ill look into that